# How to calculate height and width of object using camera only in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I want to calculate Height and width of object using camera.
I have tried for finding angle between camera and object in iphone, i think it will help to get object dimensions!

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: wt u have to tried ??

Comment: It will help to know how far the object is from the camera, and then using the calculated dimensions in the image to can calculate the object size (I assume).  So the question should be "How do you determine the distance of an object from the camera".

Comment: Is this possible without using any inputed values such as distance. I have tried with some maths functions. I need to calculate dimensions of object within the room(15feet x 15feet).

Comment: I doubt it.  We calculate distance using binocular vision and our brain is able to determine how far our eyes are crossed when focusing on a object.  An alternate system, employed by bats and dolphins, is the echo sound mechanism where they emit a sound and calculate how long the echo takes to return.  Unfortunately Apple didn't see fit to put two cameras on the iPhone/iPad, nor did they add echo sounding functionality.  How thoughtless.

Comment: This is a topic which has probably been researched by many. I would start by finding some research papers and find out what is and what is not possible. I think without multiple cameras or a referencing object in the image, this is an incredibly difficult task. @trojanfoe FYI: Moles can smell in stereo!

Comment: I am interested in Answer with some Mathematical Formulas. Interesting Question ..!!!

Comment: @Patrick And Catfish can *taste* their way through the muddy waters they inhabit...  (you probably saw that Brian Cox telly programme too...)

Answer (score 5):

The best way of doing this is to use a reference object. That can be a piece of paper or your id card whose actual dimensions are known to you. Place the reference card near to the object whose dimensions you need to calculate. Take snapshot of both. Somehow calculate the number of pixels covered by card whose actual dimensions are known (I used it using openGL in my iOS Application). Then calculate the number of pixels of the object you want to find dimensions. 
Comparing both values you can device a formula to get height and width of object.

Above is one solution that might help you. Else you need to calculate distance between object and camera (which is not possible with iPhone, as it has only one camera) and then proceed.

Comment: I can only give you directions, code is property of my client. So i cannot make it public without his consent.

Comment: how can we calculate number of pixels covered by an irregular shape?